# Oracle SQL - Get records from current month last year

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with Oracle SQL.

I'm trying to get all records from the current month and last year.

Example: This is August 12, so I want all records from 1-12 August 2017

The query gets me all records in the current month 2018.

```
BETWEEN trunc (sysdate, 'mm') AND SYSDATE
```

How to do the same for last year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ADD_MONTHS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm) function to get 12 months before:

```
Between trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-12),'mm') and trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-11),'mm')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
where date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mon') - interval '12' month and
      date < trunc(sysdate, 'mon') - interval '11' month
```